# PHP Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform

Tags: php, composer-php

I get this error from super-linter (Github actions):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.19. in /github/workspace/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.19. in /github/workspace/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

My composer file:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3||^8.0",
    "psalm/plugin-phpunit": "^0.16.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
}
```

Comment: You are running PHP7, some of your dependencies need PHP8. The error message is clear enough.

Comment: @yivi this project run without error on my localhost. this error from github actions

Comment: Which means you are using PHP7 in your github actions. Use something like [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-php-action) to specify the PHP version.

Comment: @yivi Thank you. I setup 7.3.31 in github actions. but I get this error again.

Comment: That’s exactly the opposite what you need to do. The error says you need v8. ‍♂️

Comment: @yivi but i run it on 7.4 on localhost and work fine!

Comment: Then the code you are using in the action is different. Did you run `composer install` there using PHP 8?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes I ran.

Comment: Then don't do that if you run the rest of your actions using PHP 7

Comment: I added an answer, check it out and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided us, the problem seems clear - you are running **PHP7**, and your dependencies require **PHP8**

You need to specify the PHP version or upgrade/downgrade your dependencies.

If you are using Linux, you can specify your version like this:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php7.1
$ sudo a2enmod php8.0
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

If your on windows, try reading [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-php-actionhttps://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-php-action).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The OP uses a Github action, and I would assume that it does not contain any Apache webserver to lint code